# Why does static_cast of an enum class stored in a bit-field change the result?

Tags: c++, g++, static-cast

Given an `enum class` stored in a bit-field:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

enum class Orientation: uint8_t
{
    NORMAL        = 0,
    CLOCKWISE     = 1,
    ANTICLOCKWISE = 2
};

inline Orientation operator+(const Orientation& lvalue, const Orientation& rvalue)
{
    switch(lvalue)
    {
        case Orientation::NORMAL:    return rvalue;
        case Orientation::CLOCKWISE:
            switch (rvalue)
            {
            case Orientation::CLOCKWISE:     return Orientation::ANTICLOCKWISE;
            case Orientation::ANTICLOCKWISE: return Orientation::NORMAL;
            case Orientation::NORMAL:        return Orientation::CLOCKWISE;
            }
            __builtin_unreachable();
        case Orientation::ANTICLOCKWISE:
            switch (rvalue)
            {
            case Orientation::CLOCKWISE:     return Orientation::NORMAL;
            case Orientation::ANTICLOCKWISE: return Orientation::CLOCKWISE;
            case Orientation::NORMAL:        return Orientation::ANTICLOCKWISE;
            }
            __builtin_unreachable();
    }
    __builtin_unreachable();
}

class Puzzle {
    private:
        Orientation or1_ : 2;
        Orientation or2_ : 2;

    public:
        Puzzle(
            const Orientation or1,
            const Orientation or2
        ) :
        or1_(or1),
        or2_(or2)
        {}

        bool checkPolarity() const
        {
            return (or1_ + or2_)
                   == Orientation::NORMAL;
        }

        bool checkPolarityWithCast() const
        {
            return (static_cast<Orientation>(or1_) + static_cast<Orientation>(or2_))
                   == Orientation::NORMAL;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Puzzle puzzle(
        Orientation::ANTICLOCKWISE,
        Orientation::CLOCKWISE
    );

    std::cout << "No cast: " << puzzle.checkPolarity() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Cast:    " << puzzle.checkPolarityWithCast() << '\n';
}
```

In x86-64 gcc 8.4, 8.5, 9.3, 9.4 and 9.5 the output is:

> ```
> No cast: 0
> Cast:    1
> ```

But from gcc 10, the output is:

> ```
> No cast: 1
> Cast:    1
> ```

Why does the `static_cast` make a difference to the output? Is it a bug in the compiler that was fixed from g++ 10?

*godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADsAQAOqAqETgwe3r7%2BpClpjgIhYZEsMXGJtpj2hQxCBEzEBFk%2BfgF2mA4Z9Y0ExRHRsQntDU0tOSO9/aXlwwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbsgKBPiCh9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHTqfEmKyX13e3jD57OyYCgUewA8sQ8IwGrUQHsvKECAAOAD6BG%2BJniVluexxe3CoIASgBZG5BXHk54AET2GlI33JbiCoLcAGkAOoASSE2Aph2pXDp2NxN3CABUOYzmeyuTy%2BXszOj4pTDlifjdQrRQk9wZDBExantUElYvqSNYIGgGKcwRCofqMuYAGx7WgANzEXkwpABAmtOrttSde2I7u8mDmitV5IUAHdCMgEBA3R7w/TcRioxScaIlDbddCMiAQPjiaTYbj3gRlgxg6HPSq01mc9rbXqYSBJazOdyQI2s7jY/GEHsICGUxGhf305i%2B1Pm3mA4WO0yuzLyxXMFXiDX/W2lyLxZ3pdyG5OpwCgS38/bnCADxKV8fsLDK9WF3vbyWSUFTzdz7j513AtP0Jb91wpV9t3fYC/GXKVuyuDZM3/DFlTPKdkWRKJ4VoRwGGRLwGHeJgEyYKJ6AgCMkNnADL2gm9YPvI8EN7dD%2B0HAgExHMcwwnP9/wOGc2KbOigIYotmLXCDNzfMT2y/UlfwEi9czk/cxQfeCpMgndWxgiTHwQpSBMAvTxOLUCyynHT6PbJjDJlYyUKVGis0w7C6DwgiiI%2BUjyMwSinMEtD%2BJxdycK8wjiL8iiqNVVD0VuQFgT2ZQvAAL3S%2BhBOQvYkghd0CHYVzbIyQ1iC4ZE9lhBVqOE0qBHKswqpq38%2BySLxyLwZBWNCik0syiiSvJS0/TMg0SAFYaAN9AgGprEgFXquZqpKybkQgSaFjW4hms23a%2BKnDMEtuEqolQTwAQQToAGtlE8RpCAAT0on0rTRerjvq8kbP2yqDksJrkUO5Ssz5OU1JA0sfzqvryROtUp3Oy6E1u%2B6DAhAgnrZQgEDcIECFe0aPrh6dcusmSoIgU57WQZEczRI5IYYS4/uBgGLD2GnHDphnDjcZnWcW4GQdB%2BGNmVCX5qLBSYfJ6cQoS2HvgRPYWCYUJAtOoSfgATgGrKng6waAsS3Xrl15mi3srTuUFPWLatuDVxPU6NF1uLEr6050CLNAvDm/n%2BYBsxwlQFSCFhcwzGeNxg%2BNw2ADpUeQO6Hsxl6VqDo49jAdYAFY3AYPOgp9v2lkDo5g%2Bj/HTnA6PY/jjKk5TtOMeenGCDxgnXuztxc4LouS%2BVpUOAWWhOHz3g/A4LRSFQTg48sawuaWFYnk2HhSEj2ex4WG6QA2DZE6P0%2Bz/Px19E4SRp80XgF44XgFBAWkd60BY4FgGBEBQVAWCSOgsRyCUDQP/QBcRgCImkDQXCsRn4QCiHfUgURQiNCepwLeoC2CCFBAwWg6Dd6kCwOrIw4hCH4HeF0V0mBn6EMwKoToAc1hzwRNUJBmoojEDQR4LASCCAQhYBgsefADDAAUAANUhDGUExoZ5b34IIEQYh2BSBkIIRQKh1CEN0AEAwRgUDWGsPoPAURn6QAWEaWotCAC0bIxC0D2LY%2Bh/CmCOLZJaahxA0iNVsWkYADBrEeLgWVXxcZOIIGsX8FgbjYjEBIE/aonQYQQFcOMPwApghahmEMAU%2BR0gCDSXoPJtRpiDDiAKDoXQBA9DGJ4VoehKm1BqX0LJZSGmjGaHUnIFSOmlLKDkhYCg16rD0PwzAaweDj0nrfQhD9VCIkdNYx0kg9jAGQMgPYiJE4rIgEvKwlhvS4EICQAGGwBR7A8GA%2BgxBTlmDmLwN%2Be9SDXSYFgOIlEr4cBvqQQRR8T7nwBUfS%2BM854Pyfi/bed8P7fwgEgUBADrnAItH/BFQxgC6w2HwTycDKCIMISg5gxACGYL/tggguD8FIOIYYYAZC54UKSXgahtC570MYUVJBrCJ6EI4VwolPDmEPIEUIhYVBRESKkTIxgQi1HCFEOIVRCj5BKDUEg3QAo9HGEMQcjhZiPmWIyDYuxtAHFONUC4txQSvEhLZH4gJVrvE1lCUOSJDB/hOOIHE4gCSaiFhSQwdwXT0mBADX02YuTUj5MyEGopkaSmtP6eUqovrqkdMKRUxJVS6i9ITeG2waaY09KmLmgZixlgjIFGMiZwjuVT1ICC%2B%2BnB5mLOWas9ZexdYnxHHsoxewjlEBuZvb0lzUWDrMGc%2B5kLd5zH3ofY%2BgLAWX25d83586F0X3rUgsFtgIWPOhfAWFv8rlAIoMi49ECuAaAFDAoqXjcVIIJWgmVWCoQUoIfSzAJDaWCqIXgShjhmVILZcgJhnLBBsJ5SYvlT0BV8OFdwYRYqmBiMkZgaRsiZVKqUQq6BsgNGqu0YffQNKDHLx1SYvVFikhWM4LY%2BxMTzVcMtQITxjq3F2sCSx4JPjbVhITK691bJYnxOTYy5w/rA3ZGDZkkobSI0FAyOmvIcaMhhpyaJrNzSlONO6Dm2Tib2m9G03pgYBmuCDOGSo7e7xq1TI4HWht88m0LKWSstZGzL2Jy4N27VNg%2B34AHac85I7wGnI2JOvddmV1zv%2Beu0%2Bm7ZmcHBa/KFs6/lxbPkuzgGwZmgqS1O9%2BpBP5QBhUgCuHUCBIvheA8IrA1jNtc22jZWzvmYACyQPAvtr2yGwyo3D6iVVaLnjo0gMYuFJBFZ8hzW7OCggDhVw0VA9gNdbe5zZ2zu0otC5sO5DzUvPI%2BG8ygs7L20mXbwVdidHT50RPnDY13bv3Zu5IaQjnt3PxS9OorpWQDlYDlVrb1zatsGcy2tz7aWu8Da8ciEXXZW9YkP15Vmi1V6DG0wCbX3a25cbRwObBAFuoCWyt8HGzO0bE2%2BeoLEX9svKOx887PyYt3Yeyzm7LPgUzcfjuz7hXiuHr%2B5V091Wgd1dB41tbnmt7Q4HZ1vQWH5V9dlfhobOgiPo8x5MqbOOnN4/mwHRby2XOrfbVLyno6ws0%2BnQsOnQwGfXwu4fMwidEQaEkIieIrv3ee7d7rBLeXucfYK08g%2B6WMtH0%2BTl/3uO9vW8%2BWYHX27IukFY4WSQQA%3D%3D)*

Comment: Because g++ 8.4 and 9.3 don't call the custom `operator+`. I guess they do integer promotion for the `+` and then the equality is false. Bug or not? Probably.

Comment: Looks like a fixed bug indeed: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92859

Comment: Very good, @goswin (and you, @Yksisarvinen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With G++8.4, the assembly code for `Puzzle.checkPolarity()` is:

```
Puzzle::checkPolarity() const:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        and     eax, 3
        mov     edx, eax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        shr     al, 2
        and     eax, 3
        add     eax, edx
        test    al, al
        sete    al
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

And, as [commented by Goswin von Brederlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454299/why-does-static-cast-of-an-enum-class-stored-in-a-bit-field-change-the-result?noredirect=1#comment127995019_72454299)

> Because g++ 8.4 and 9.3 don't call the custom `operator+`. I guess they do integer promotion for the `+` and then the equality is false.

As [commented by Yksisarvinen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454299/why-does-static-cast-of-an-enum-class-stored-in-a-bit-field-change-the-result?noredirect=1#comment127995078_72454299)

> Looks like a fixed bug indeed: [gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92859](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92859)

---

However, that bug report states:

> [Comment 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92859#c5) Jason Merrill 2019-12-19 14:23:49 UTC
>
> Fixed for 8.4/9.3/10.

and it appears that it has not entirely been fixed as it is still appearing to be bugged in x86-64 gcc 8.4, 8.5, 9.3, 9.4 and 9.5 but the fix does appear to have worked from version 10.